# Page not recognised?

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, model

The controller doesn't seem to be recognizing my view page when I try to load it in the browser. The view page itself is called `insertjob.php` and controller is called client therefore the link should be `website_url/client/insertjob`.

I have uploaded it to a serve and the home page works but the insert job page doesn't load even though the link is correct.

Controller

```
public function addjobsform()
{
$this->load->helper('form');
$data['title']="Add a new job";
$this->load->view("insertjob", $data);
}
```

View

```
<h1>Welcome to XYZ inc.</h1> 
<p>Find out everything you need to know about the XYZ company</p> 

<div id="nav"
<ul> 
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('nav/home');?>">Home</a><li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('client/insertjob');?>">Insert</a></li>
</ul>
```

Model

```
<?php

class cmodel extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
parent:: __construct();   
}

function getjob(){
$query = $this->db->get('client');
return $query->result();
}

}
function addjob($jobtype,$jobinfo)
{
    $newjob=array("jobtype"=>$jobtype,"jobinfo"=>$jobinfo);
    return $this->db->insert('client', $newjob);
}

}
?>
```

Comment: try website_url/index.php/client/addjobsform

Comment: thank you, worked fine, it was the function name.... thanks

Comment: i have an answer for this

Answer (score 1):

your are using wrong url

try

```
website_url/index.php/client/addjobsform
```

or

```
website_url/index.php/controller/controllerfunction
```